# Several metals were misused

Tags: riddle, knowledge

A metal was misused to choke people.

Another metal was misused to destroy people's bones.

Yet another, radioactive metal was misused to act as a biological messenger.

What are these metals, and how were they misused?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My best guess is that the metals are

> Cobalt, Hafnium, and Nobelium

and the way they were misused is with

> Caps Lock.

Misused this way, instead of being metals, they became compounds with the given properties:

> A metal was misused to choke people.

> Co = Cobalt
>  CO = Carbon Monoxide, a common cause of asphyxiation

> Another metal was misused to destroy people's bones.

> Hf = Hafnium
>  HF = Hydrofluoric Acid, "readily penetrates human skin, allowing it to destroy soft tissues underneath and to decalcify bone" ([source](https://ehs.ucsc.edu/lab-safety-manual/specialty-chemicals/hydrofluoric-acid.html))

> Yet another, radioactive metal was misused to act as a biological messenger.

> No = Nobelium (synthetic element, all isotopes radioactive)
>  NO = Nitric Oxide, "a major messenger molecule regulating immune function and blood vessel dilatation and serving as a neurotransmitter in the brain and peripheral nervous system" ([source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/sdfe/pdf/download/eid/1-s2.0-009286749290301R/first-page-pdf))

Comment: Puzzles and answers like these make me feel low about my weak brain! Great job!!

Comment: @Techidiot this was definitely one of the harder solves, seeing how there are three "degrees of freedom" from to "which metal" to "how would you misuse a metal" to "how to interpet the misuse clue". Therefore the actual solution was either something super rigid like this, or nothing solvable at all, an assumption which I shamelessly abused. (Alongside ptable.com, of course)